# How to get rid of windows title bar in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, html, windows, cordova

I want to disable or remove the title bar in my app. Something like native windows apps having their own customized title bar and minimize and maximize buttons.

Can I do this using `JavaScript` or any other scripting language in `Cordova` app?

**Please keep in mind that I'm working in `Cordova` app `JavaScript`. Can I do this in `Cordova` app?**

Please help me.

Thanks

[Image of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqkHH.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. You can expand the client area to blend in with the title bar and you can even customize the title bar, but you cannot get rid of it.

Comment: then how to customize the title bar ? or expand the client area ? and thanks :)

Comment: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/  you'd have to adapt this to a Cordova plugin. On Windows Cordova apps are you UWP apps not traditional desktop apps. That article does touch upon removing it but I've never tried it and highly recommend even if you can that you don't as it's non standard for Windows UWP apps. There was also a Windows 7 specific branch of Cordova created by Intel that they've been removed but somebody forked on github. The problem is you are then pinned to an old version

Comment: and can't use later plugins and would also have to customize the title bar for a desktop app, so again not recommended. Why is it you want to do this?